# How does one release memory correctly in the attached C array?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, cocoa

I'm just trying to work out why the following code is leaking memory and I have a funny feeling that i'm not releasing the array memory correctly. This is a C function in a wider objective-c app and I'm not native to C... i've tried just using free() on the array, but have a feeling this isn't the whole story...

Could someone have a look and see what I'm missing here. Thanks!

```
CFIndex theNumberOfSettings = 3;
CTParagraphStyleSetting theSettings[3] =
{
    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(CTTextAlignment), &alignment},
    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineSpacing, sizeof(lineSpacing), &lineSpacing},
    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierHeadIndent, sizeof(headIndent), &headIndent}
};

CTParagraphStyleRef theParagraphRef = CTParagraphStyleCreate(theSettings, theNumberOfSettings);

CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrString, CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(attrString)-1), kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, theParagraphRef);

CFRelease(theParagraphRef);
free(theSettings);
```

Comment: The leak is of the paragraph object: You Created it, but you did not Release it. Core Text follows the Core Foundation memory management rules: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/ (Speaking of which: Since when does Core Text exist on the iPhone?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't free memory that's not allocated on the heap.

Comment: To confirm: The array above does not need to be freed, and the above code (exclusive of the CT types) shouldn't cause a memory-leak

Comment: Stronger: You *must not* free the array above. Only things that have been malloc()ed should be free()d. Trying to free pointers that haven't been returned by malloc is an error. The memory for that array will automatically be reclaimed when the function or method returns.

Comment: In other words: `free` -ing something that has not been `malloc` -ed is undefined behavior. A memory leak is an interesting behavior, it could have the iPhone exploding instead.

Comment: I have the same above issue, but I am using CFRelease(theSettings) - however my code is leaking memory too. Any thoughts?